# How to test the following : Using React JS - jest / enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I am trying to run an unit test for the following:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
let localState = Object.assign({}, this.state)
localState[e.target.name] = e.target.value
this.setState(localState)
this.props.addMetaInformation(localState)
}
 }
```

I ran an unit test for most of the file but not really sure how to run for the code above. How could I test the method or a function above based on the code below 
Thanks

```
   describe('Component', () => {

   let tree;
   let baseProps; 
 // let this.props = let mockprops
  beforeEach(() => {
  // props : mockprops;
          }
  })
it ('should render without a  props ',() => {
 baseProps = {
 ...baseProps,
 //props: {},

};
   tree = renderer.create(<Component {...baseProps } />)
  let treeJson = tree.toJSON();
  expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
  tree.unmount()
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
it ('should return meta-input-correct',() => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...baseProps } />);
 wrapper.setState({test: 'test'});
 expect(wrapper.instance().getElementId('test')).toEqual('meta-input-correct');
};

it ('should return meta-input-incorrect',() => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...baseProps } />);
 wrapper.setState({nameString: 'test'});
 expect(wrapper.instance().getElementId('testing')).toEqual('meta-input-incorrect');
};
```

Comment: THe 2nd TEST  passes but the first one i get an error :  Expected value to equal:
      "meta-input-correct"
    Received:
      "meta-input-incorrect",  could you check it please

Comment: it ('should return meta-input-correct',() => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...baseProps } />);
 wrapper.setState({test: 'test'});
 expect(wrapper.instance().getElementId('test')).toEqual('meta-input-correct');
};

Comment: It worked , you think I could apply the same content to the following code that I updated or is it something different ? thank you

Comment: which line ?   wrapper.setState({test: 'test'}); ?

Comment: no while calling method. wrapper.instance().handleChange({target: {value : 'test'}});

Comment: TypeError: this.props.addMetaInformation is not a function error when running the new test - look into it later

Comment: it ('should test handleChange method ',() => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...baseProps } />);
 wrapper.setState({test: 'test'});
expect(wrapper.instance().handleChange({target: {value : 'test'}})
);

Comment: could you check your code again - to make sure its working correct